# psychologically , which color for which lesson?

Tags: psychology, color

Imagine I have an educational website which hosts high school students and presents lessons like chemistry, physics, mathematics, etc. Now I want to give each one of my lessons a unique color. I thought maybe there is a psychological thing about this. Is there? If so, could any one give such resource that tells me what color is suitable for chemistry and so on.

Comment: Drunk Tank Pink is a great read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't ever seen material which describes links between colors and some knowledge fields. To my mind, it depends on your *own experience*. But there are a lot of material about common feelings of different colors, that could be helpful for design, for organization of any kind of information. Look [here](https://precisionintermedia.com/color) and [here](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/psychology-of-color-and-conversions/).